# Update timestamp in postgresSQL after a tuple update

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table X with 4 attributes and several tuples of information. One of those attributes called 'Update Date' collects the current timestamp of when those records were introduced to the table.

So, what I would like is to implement a function and trigger that will update the 'Update Date' attribute of a record when a change occurs in that record only, indicating the new CURRENT TIMESTAMP.

For example,

In a record ('Susan', 'Parker', '27',05-05-2020 00:00:00:00), I want that changing the first field 'Susan' will also cause a change in the fourth attribute with the new current timestamp.

I have tried to implement the function as follows:

I imagine that the function must include UPDATE for them to be entered and I have performed the function this way but it is not implemented correctly.

```
CREATE FUNCTION function()
RETURNS trigger language plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.attribute1 <> OLD.attribute1) THEN
        UPDATE table SET Date_update DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    END IF;
    IF (NEW.attribute2 <> OLD.attribute2) THEN
        UPDATE table SET Date_update DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    END IF;
    IF (NEW.attribute3 <> OLD.attribute3) THEN
        UPDATE table SET Date_update DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    END IF;
    RETURN DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
END;
$$;
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE function();
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Comment: You have not shown the trigger definition, add it as update to question. Assuming it is an `ON UPDATE` you don't want to do  `UPDATE table ...` as that will setup a recursion. Instead just do `NEW.Date_update = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and then `RETURN NEW`. You need to spend time here [trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Comment: Sorry Adrian, I just added the trigger. It seems to be much simpler with your solution, however I need to include UPDATE in the function.  Is there any way to implement it? Thank you very much for your intervention

Comment: @yuda But wouldn't doing an update in the trigger just evoke another trigger?  Andrian's method seems legit. Should give it test run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested but it should be something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION function()
RETURNS trigger language plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.* <> OLD.*) THEN
        NEW.Date_update = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    END IF;
    
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE function();
```

`NEW.* <> OLD.*` will test for any change in the `NEW` tuple vs the `OLD` one. If there is a change then `NEW.Date_update = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` sets the value of `Date_update` in the `NEW` tuple and `RETURN NEW;` returns the modified `NEW` tuple. Trigger was changed to `BEFORE` so the `RETURN NEW` works.

Comment: Would there be a between `NEW.* <> OLD.*` and `NEW <> OLD`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I'm not understanding your question can you elaborate?

Comment: What is the difference when you compare the two records between expanding all columns using `.*` and comparing the records directly. I always use `new <> old` and I wonder if there is any functional (or performance) difference in expanding the columns using `new.* <> old.*`

Comment: Habit on my part. If I remember correctly there was a time `new <> old` did not work and you had to expand the `record` via `new.* <> old.*` to get a comparison.  I can't find the change note at the moment, if I do find it I will add in another comment.

Comment: @yuda, it works for you would you go ahead and accept the answer.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Excuse me. I'm new to Stackoverflow and I barely know how some things work. I'll get right on it :)